# How to bind to Class using Generics in XAML

Tags: vb.net, xaml, generics, binding

I have created a simple class like this one...

```
 Public Class Localizer(Of T)

        Public Shared ReadOnly Property DisplayName(ByVal propertyName As String) As String
            Get
               ...
            End Get
        End Property

    End Class
```

And I'm attempting to bind to it in XAML something like this...

```
Header="{x:Static loc:Localizer(Of AircraftReference).DisplayName [IsMilitary]}"
```

But this must not be the right syntax. This may not even be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here.

1. XAML support for generics is [not complete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee956431.aspx); I don't think you can specify the type parameter in XAML.

   However, there's an easy workaround for this problem:

   ```
   Public Class Localizer(Of T)
       Public Shared ReadOnly Property DisplayName As String
           Get
              ...
           End Get
       End Property
   End Class

   Public Class AircraftReferenceLocalizer
       Inherits Localizer(Of AircraftReference)
   End Class
   ```

   Now you can use:

   ```
   Header="{x:Static loc:AircraftReferenceLocalizer.DisplayName}"
   ```
2. [`x:Static`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742135.aspx) does not support parameterized properties, so you cannot pass the string "IsMilitary". I'm afraid you'll have to find a solution without `x:Static`. It might make sense to describe want problem you want to solve and ask for a solution in a new question.

Comment: Thanks very much. That tells me what I needed to know.